# Highlight entry if not 17 numeric digits

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

Basically, I'm part of a community and when someone applies for membership, they have to provide a Player ID in their application. When we accept their application, we copy information into a Google Spreadsheet about them such as Player ID's and GUID. We want a way of indicating on our spreadsheet if the Player ID is incorrect. If the number put in is less than 17 digits in length or is any bigger, it would indicate that it's wrong by either formatting the cell to be a light red or it being replaced with "ERROR". I just need something that would indicate if it's incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to **Format** tab in the google spreedsheet, then go to **Conditional Formatting**, then in the **Apply to range** box, put down your range, say **A1:A30** the range where you want to apply your formatting. Then, in the **Format cells if**, choose **Custom formula is**, the last one in the dropdown list. Then put this formula in the formula box just below it:

```
=and(not(len(A1)=17),not(isblank(a1)))
```

then in the formatting style, choose any color that suits you. Then click **DONE**. It should work!

### Update

in a helper column, say column **B**, you can put this formula in **B1** and copy down until the last row:

```
=If(isblank(A1),"",(IF(LEN(A1)=17,"OK","ERROR")))
```

this should work

Comment: Would it be possible to have it replace it with Error? But thanks anyway this is really good!

Comment: this should be done a helper column. Because you cannot replace the wrong ID number with an error message. This can be done using a VBA though. But you allow for a separate helper column, then you can add a formula in there and say if the digit is 17, then OK if not ERROR.

Comment: helper column is another empty column that you use to help you calculate certain formula and display the results because you cannot touch the columns with data. So here, supposing that your data is in column A and your column B is empty. so you can use this empty column as your helper column to help you calculate the formula and see which cell is OK or ERROR.